# How to disable web app prompt on ubuntu 15.04 and Firefox 38?

Tags: firefox, 15.04

The option was available on Edit > Preferences > Desktop Integration > Untick “Prompt integration options for any website” before. Any idea how I can disable those prompts now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unity Tweak Tool" In the repository (Software Center), has an on/off button within the 'Web Apps' section to turn off prompts for the Unity Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by disabling Unity desktop integration from Modules > Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "modules" it's "add-ons" in Firefox 38. This menu is found by clicking on the "hamburger" icon in the right top corner OR under "tools" in the dropdown Firefox menu hidden at the top of the screen, then select "add-ons". In the resulting overview tick "extensions" and untick "Unity website integration" and anything else you didn't know you wanted.

I now understand why everthing in Linux is broken and I have to Google everything. Using Linux is as fun as dancing in broken glass.